# UWP sending message to Windows Service using NamedPipes

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp, windows-services, named-pipes

I'm trying to create a UWP app for our tools, one of its functionality is to manage tfs outside visual studio using tf.exe console commands and other things, i noticed that UWP is sandboxed and only has limited access outside its deployment folder so im planning to use a windows service to be the one who will be doing all the heavy work and using NamedPipes to communicate between UWP and Windows Service, been searching a bit already but until now im still not able to establish connection between this 2 app

I'm using console as a sample and starting it from UWP using FullTrustProcessLuncher

I uploaded a sample project in github
https://github.com/vgdagpin/UWP2WindowsService

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about named pipes so I can't tell if that is correct. But generally, UWP apps use [APP services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) to communicate with desktop apps because the app service is native UWP.

I'd suggest you take a look at @Stefan Wick's Blog - UWP with Desktop Extension Part 1,2,3. You could search for them in your browser. These tutorials show the way how to package desktop apps with UWP apps using Windows Application Packaging Project and how to establish communication between the UWP app and the console app using App service which should be what exactly you want. After you launched the console app from the UWP app, you could let the console app call the windows service to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried AppServiceConnection now, since I used NetCore 5.0 I referenced nuget package Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT, my new challenge now is I keep on getting AppServiceUnavailable

Comment: @VincentDagpin Based on the document: [AppServiceConnectionStatus Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appservice.appserviceconnectionstatus?view=winrt-22000), `AppServiceUnavailable` means the app service and the version of the app are correct. Maybe you could try the sample code from the Blog first, then replace the desktop app with the console app you are using.

Comment: Already done that and no luck :), i updated my github repo with the recent example, will try again another later

Comment: @VincentDagpin Do you mean even the sample form the blog does not work?

Comment: I got it working now, I just need to separate my background task in separate project (Windows Runtime Component)

I updated github repo for reference